# Unable to locate package ncurses

Tags: ncurses

I was trying to install **ncurses** on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with the following line:

`sudo apt-get install libncurses6-dev libncursesw6-dev`

I get this output:

```
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libncurses6-dev
E: Unable to locate package libncursesw6-dev
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4):

To install ncurses, try `sudo apt install ncurses`

For the -dev package, try `sudo apt install libncurses-dev`

There are no -dev packages for libncurses6 nor for libncursesw6.